# The sets $\{-x,x\}$ form a partition of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

I've been really trying to understand how some of these proofs work; I've spent a majority of my time studying the material for this class, but I'm still performing poorly in it. It doesn't help that the book is very vague; what's worse is that it contains little to no solutions and does not have a solutions manual, so I don't even know if I'm right or wrong half the time.

Anyways, in the problem, we are asked to prove that a set is a partition. A problem from the book:

> Prove that $P=\left\{X: X = \{-x,x\} \space \text{and} \space x\in\mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}\right\}$ is a partition on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Recalling that the three criteria of a partition are that:

1. If $X$ is an element of the partition, $X$ cannot be empty.
2. If $X$ and $Y$ are elements of the partition, they are equal or pairwise disjoint.
3. The union of all the elements in the partition are equal to the set we are taking the partition of.

I'd greatly appreciate help. I understand what the criteria demand intuitively, but I just can't seem to connect the logic when I do the proofs.

Comment: The first step that I would recommend is sitting down and rewriting the entire problem on a new piece of paper but **WITHOUT** the clash of variables where $x$ has two entirely different meanings in the same problem. So, in properties i), ii) replace $x$ and $y$ by something like $A$ and $B$.

Comment: After that, then start from the beginning. Regarding criterion i): Assuming $A$ is an element of the partition, you must prove that $A$ is not empty. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  For i), I pick some arbitrary value and let it be an element of the set.  This demonstrates that it is not empty.

Comment: Is it just me or is this post now less readible after the edit?

Comment: I don't know what happened I don't really use stackexchange.  Someone edited it and it was much better and I accepted the edit but then it went back to what it was prior the edit.  I'm a noob, sorry.

Comment: Remember that a family of subsets of a certain set $\;A\;$ is a *partition* iff those subsets are the equivalence classes of some equivalence class on $\;A\times A\;$ . Now, try to enhance big time the way your question looks, among other things by writing down the actual problem and not just linking to it. You can get help writing correctly mathematics in this site here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Your strategy for i) is not valid. You may not "pick an arbitrary value and let it be an element of the set". Instead, you must use the assumption that $A$ is an element of the partition. What does that assumption, together with the definition of the partition, tell you about the format of $A$, and how does that tell you that $A$ is nonempty?

Comment: If **A** is an element of the partition, then a is element of **A** so that a is either {-a, a} or {0}.  Then, **A** is not empty.

Comment: You are on the right track, but your mathematical grammar is faulty. It you reword slightly then it works: if $A$ is an element of the partition then $A$ is either $\{-a,a\}$ or $\{0\}$, so $A$ is not empty.

Comment: @badeconomist I edited your question to try to clear up the confusion between integers $x$ and partions $x \in P$. Does it look okay?

Comment: @graydad: It's better to use the markdown for lists. If you insist on using MathJax, $\mathit{iii}$ is better than $iii$ because of spacing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria demands that when you and your friends order a pizza and you each take a part of the pizza:

1. Every one got some part of the pizza.
2. No two people ate from the same slice.
3. You ate the entire pizza.

As for the proof, my best advice is once you get the intuitive idea, or even well before that, just work with the definitions carefully and slowly.

You have to prove that if $X\in P$, then $X$ is not empty. How do we do that? Let $X\in P$ be an arbitrary element, then by definition there is some $x\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ such that $X=\{-x,x\}$. In particular $x\in X$, so $X$ is not empty.

You have to prove that if $X\neq Y$ are elements from $P$, then $X\cap Y=\varnothing$. So again, you pick two elements from $P$ which are different, and you show that if $x\in X$, then $x\notin Y$ and vice versa.

Finally you have to prove that if $k\in\Bbb Z$, then for some $X\in P$ we have $k\in X$. And I'll let you try to figure out what to do on this one all alone.

Comment: On ii), I think I understand now.  In the formal proof, you just let {-x, x} and {-y, y} be either {0} or some natural, show that they aren't the same, and therefore, their intersection is null?

Comment: @badeconomist "either $\{0\}$ or some natural" is equivalent to saying "some integer in $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$." You shouldn't need to consider the case of zero or nonzero. Just the case of $x=y$ or $x \neq y$

Comment: On ii), what's preventing me from saying that two arbitrary sets X and Y are equal because their elements can both be 0, so that {0, 0} = {0, 0}?  Sorry i'm just really confused and i'm not familiar with the commands and it's making it difficult to reply.

Comment: @badeconomist: You begin by saying "these two sets are not equal". If they end up equal, you've made a mistake or found a contradiction.